# SQL syntax error when creating a script stored procedure in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an error when I create a stored procedure in mysql

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE insertvaluefield(IN p_field INT) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE v_type VARCHAR(80) DEFAULT '';
    SELECT type_field 
    FROM Field 
    WHERE id_field = p_field 
    LIMIT 1; 
    IF v_type IN ('text', 'textarea') THEN
        DELETE FROM ValueField 
        WHERE field_valuefield = p_field;
    END IF;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

I do this to save this procedure in my database :

```
mysql -uXXXX -pXXXX DataBase < script.sql
```

This is a result error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE insertvaluefield(IN p_field INT) BEGIN DECLARE v_ty' at line 1
```

Comment: you can path database name via flag `-D` (example: `mysql -uXXXX -pXXXX -DDataBase < script.sql)`

Comment: I try with option D, it didn't work too

Comment: Why dont you create it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Correct Syntax to execute SQL script from Terminal is:

`mysql -uXXXX -pXXXX  -e "use your_db_name; source path_to_sql_file/script.sql;"`

Check the output also, It is showing in test DB:

`mysql> show procedure status;`

```
+------+------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+------- ---------------+--------------------+
| Db   | Name             | Type      | Definer        | Modified            | Created             | Security_type | Comment | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+------+------------------+-----------+----------------+-------------------- -+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| test | insertvaluefield | PROCEDURE | root@localhost | 2015-11-19 21:18:34 | 2015-11-19 21:18:34 | DEFINER       |         | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+------+------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I try you method like this : mysql -uXXXX -pXXXX -e "use WorkApplication; source ./proc.sql;", but I still have the same error :/,
I try to launch this script after I'm connected on mysql, he didn't work too

Comment: I have just copy pasted your SQL code and created `script.sql` file and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. In my test case everything works as expected.

Remember to assign `type_field` to `v_type`:

```sql
...
-- SELECT `type_field`
SELECT `type_field` INTO `v_type`
...
```

File: `/path/to/file/script.sql`

```sql
USE `test`;

DELIMITER //

SELECT DATABASE()//

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Field`//
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insertvaluefield`//

CREATE TABLE `Field` (
  `id_field` INT,
  `type_field` VARCHAR(80)
)//

CREATE PROCEDURE `insertvaluefield`(IN `p_field` INT) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE `v_type` VARCHAR(80) DEFAULT '';
    -- SELECT `type_field`
    SELECT `type_field` INTO `v_type`
    FROM `Field` 
    WHERE `id_field` = `p_field`
    LIMIT 1;
    IF `v_type` IN ('text', 'textarea') THEN
        /*
        DELETE FROM ValueField 
        WHERE field_valuefield = p_field;
        */

        /* TEST CASE */
        SELECT CONCAT('
                  DELETE FROM `ValueField`
                  WHERE `field_valuefield` = ', `p_field`, ';
               ') `DELETE`;
    END IF;
END//

INSERT INTO `Field`
  (`id_field`, `type_field`)
VALUES
  (1, 'text'),
  (2, 'textarea')//

DELIMITER ;

CALL `insertvaluefield`(1)\G
CALL `insertvaluefield`(2)\G
```

Test:

```bsh
$ mysql -u XXXX -p  < /path/to/file/script.sql
Enter password: 
DATABASE()
test
*************************** 1. row ***************************
DELETE: 
                  DELETE FROM `ValueField`
                  WHERE `field_valuefield` = 1;

*************************** 1. row ***************************
DELETE: 
                  DELETE FROM `ValueField`
                  WHERE `field_valuefield` = 2;
```